# Is there a way to hide fragments or IDs when the app starts?

Tags: android

I'm doing a program where the user selects an option with a radio button 
and the number of fragments appear.
EX: If they choose 2 then two color fragments appear

I tried putting the IDs as a variable and then an if statement

```
RadioButton rb1 = ( RadioButton ) findViewById(R.id.radio_one);
        RadioButton rb2 = ( RadioButton ) findViewById(R.id.radio_two);
        LinearLayout GS = ( LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.id.game_state);
        LinearLayout GR = (LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.id.game_result);
        radioButton = findViewById(radioId);
            if (rb1.isChecked())
                GS.bringToFront();
            else if (rb2.isChecked())
                GR.bringToFront();
```

But I don't think bringToFront() is the right method to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bringToFront() is methode inherite from Android's View class, and works on an other way: [bringToFront](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront())

> change the view's z order in the tree, so it's on top of other sibling views. This ordering change may affect layout, if the parent container uses an order-dependent layout scheme (e.g., LinearLayout)

think about if you have textView1 and textView2 in your LinearLayout, and what you can do with bringToFront()

a professional developer would do that what you want to do, with fragments, or may be a framelayout but you can also try this [setVisibilaty()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))

```
RadioButton rb1 = ( RadioButton ) findViewById(R.id.radio_one);
    RadioButton rb2 = ( RadioButton ) findViewById(R.id.radio_two);
    LinearLayout GS = ( LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.id.game_state);
    LinearLayout GR = (LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.id.game_result);
    radioButton = findViewById(radioId);
        if (rb1.isChecked()){
            GS.setVisibility(0);
            GR.setVisibility(2)}
        else if (rb2.isChecked()){
           GS.setVisibility(2);
            GR.setVisibility(0);
 }
```